# how to add record to JTable via Button?

Tags: java, jtable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RACAM.png)

Please help.
how to do. each time I click jbutton the qty and price will +++

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), 
[How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should create JTable object with DefaultTableModel as an constructor argument.
e.g.

`DefaultTableModel tableModel=new DefaultTableModel();`

```
 tableModel.addColumn("Menu");



tableModel.addColumn("Quantity");



tableModel.addColumn("Price");



JTable jtable=new JTable(tableModel);
```

To add row on button click,You can use this code in button click event
  `tableModel.addRow("Pizza","2","240");`.like this
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DefaultTableModel` class to set the value of table's cell. See example below:

```
JTable table = newJTable();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.setRowCount(2); //Set the number of rows to be added.
model.setValueAt("Row0Col0", 0, 0); //First parameter is Value, second is row number and Third is column Number
model.setValueAt("Row1Col0", 1, 0);
model.setValueAt("Row0Col1", 0, 1);
model.setValueAt("Row1Col1", 1, 1);
```